# how to pass timestamp between python/sql

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azxPt.png)

```
%python
df =spark.sql(" select count(*) from sample.table_c")
count = df.first()[0]

spark.conf.set("myapp.count",count)
spark.conf.get("myapp.count")
```

i am getting count & saving it as variable  for further use in sql..

---

### the above code is working for int,string ..but when i am using it for timestamp,date instead of int..i am getting error

```
%python

import datetime as dt

c_time =dt.datetime.now()
spark.conf.set("myapp.ages",c_time)
```

the error is
py4j.Py4JException: Method set([class java.lang.String, class java.sql.Timestamp]) does not exist

any way to solve this,please help me

i tried widgets concept...but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error because Spark's set function doesn't work with date and time data, only text. You can get around this by turning your date and time into text

```
get_time = dt.datetime.now()
get_time_str = str(get_time)  
spark.conf.set("myapp.ages", get_time_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, this should help.

```
import datetime as dt
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Get the current timestamp
current_time = dt.datetime.now()

# Convert the Python datetime object to a java.sql.Timestamp object
java_timestamp = F.to_timestamp(F.lit(current_time))

# Set the configuration with the java.sql.Timestamp value
spark.conf.set("myapp.ages", java_timestamp)

# Verify the configuration value
ages_config = spark.conf.get("myapp.ages")
print(ages_config)  # This will print the timestamp value in the Spark configuration
```

Comment: spark.conf.set("myapp.ages", java_timestamp)


getting error in this line --



TypeError: Column is not iterable